# QEgl::display(): Cannot initialize EGL display: "Success (0x3000)" Error QML

Tags: qt, qml, egl

I am building an App using Qt/QML. I can successfully compile it but while running I am getting this error:

```
QEgl::display(): Cannot initialize EGL display: "Success (0x3000)" 
QEglContext::chooseConfig(): Could not find a suitable EGL configuration 
Requested: "type=es2 rgba=0,0,0,0 surface-type=window" 
Available:
```

Also, it does not show any available configurations. I put some console logs in QML file, but they are never displayed in console. However, I can see logs from c++ code.

Comment: You need to at least tell us the Qt version in use and describe your hardware and the software stack you have on the target device.

Comment: I am using QT 4.8 . Can you please tell me Why I am getting this error ? I am using WebView in QML .